# Syntax error near unexpected token 'GTK'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install the gtkterm2 application on my linux ubuntu machine but it didnt worked.

This is error which is shown during the build process:

```
../gtkterm2-0.2.3/configure: line 13727: syntax error near unexpected token `GTK,'
../gtkterm2-0.2.3/configure: line 13727: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK, gtk+-2.0 gdk-2.0,,exit)'
```

Can someone help me on this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use gtkterm2, it's so old and unmaintained. It's better to `apt-get install gtkterm`

Comment: @IporSircer actually I am building Yocto image so i need to install the gtkterm2 package to it. if its ubuntu i can just use the `apt-get install gtkterm`

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `gtk+2.0` with command `apt-get install gtk2.0`